# ruby and javascript hmac signatures do not match giving same values

Tags: javascript, ruby, openssl, sha256, hmac

i am trying to conect my backend in ruby on rails with and end point and it asks for hmac signature of every request. they gave me an .html with some javascript that returns in the explorer console their value of hmac given a key and a payload, but when i do the equivalent code in ruby on rails it gives me a diferent value given the same parameters. next i am pasting the html AND my code in ruby, i need my ruby code to give the javascript answer.

i have tried changing the encoding of the inputs o my code to ascii, iso8859-1, and utf-8.
i have comprared my hmac answer to answers given by multiple hmac generator in the internet and they give my answer exepto for 1 page whitch gives the javascript answer.
this is the one that gives de javascript answer: https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/

this is the javascreipt from the third party

```
function toHex (message) {
 var str = '', c;
 for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
  c = message.charCodeAt(i);
  str += c.toString(16) ;
 }
 return str;
}

function sign(originalMessage, key){
 var message =toHex(originalMessage);
 var signature, hmac;    
 hmac = new sjcl.misc.hmac(sjcl.codec.hex.toBits(key), 
sjcl.hash.sha256);
 signature =sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(hmac.encrypt(sjcl.codec.hex.toBits(message)));
  return signature;
}
```

this is my code:
    def toHex(message)
      str = ''
      caracter = 0
      cont = 0
      while(cont < message.length) do
        caracter = message[cont].ord
        str = str + caracter.to_s(16)
        cont = cont + 1
      end
      return str
    end

```
def sign(original_message, key)
  #byebug
  message = toHex(original_message)
  signature = ''
  signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest("SHA256", key, message)
  return signature
end
```

Comment: In 99% of all cases where someone asks a question that given the same input the same algorithm gives different results, it turns out that they were *not* giving the same input; in 1% it turns out they were not using the same algorithm.

Comment: i do think you are correct, but i can not find the diference.

Comment: Different encodings, different normalization, different line endings (or one has a line ending and the other doesn't) are the most common culprits.